# python file.write adding multiple lines in for loop

Tags: python

In the following code the output adds each line 2 times

```
template_file = open("../conf/"+config_template_code+".tmpl",'r')
        config_out = open("../sites-enabled/"+domain_name+".conf",'w')
        for line in template_file:
                config_out.write(line.replace('CPANELIP',cpanel_ipv4))
                config_out.flush()
                config_out.write(line.replace('DOMAINNAME',domain_list))
                config_out.flush()
        template_file.close()
        config_out.close()
```

If i comment out one of the config_out.write it is fine; but I want 2 in place replacements in the file .

Comment: As a side note, flushing is an expensive operation and unneeded here. Just write and close (or use a with clause). Your data will get where it needs to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the `line.replace()` twice, and the `config_out.write()` once:

```
                line = line.replace('CPANELIP',cpanel_ipv4)
                line = line.replace('DOMAINNAME',domain_list)
                config_out.write(line)
                config_out.flush()
```